# Can I change skin colors without using bitmaps?

Tags: delphi

In Bitmap Style manager when I need to change form client area or borders I have to select it from the `Bitmap` property left click + right click then apply. But I want to ask is there a way to change colors from the `Color` property instead ? or everything must be bitmaps

[image]

Comment: No, if you want to change the colors of any element of a VCL Style, you must create a new image, strictly the same size as the original, as the elements have fixed locations in the image. You will benefit from reading the web site of the VCL Styles guru "RRUZ", https://theroadtodelphi.com/ I recall there are examples from years back of creating new color schemes.

Comment: This style system is very bad sometimes any small change make Delphi produce error and AV so I have to make backup like every second !!

Answer (score -2):

i am using RAD 10.3.3
you can find on TForm properties.
on VCL
Color = $your color

on FMX
set Fill > Kind = Solid after that you can set color on Fill > color

Comment: This is not correct! Note that the question is about changing an elements (the form border in this case) color when using a VCL Style. The VCL Style engine uses the color from the Style data.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You should read the question again more closely.